# Multiple Session using port 1081 in one box using SSH

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I am setting Linux Hopping Station to another different servers.

My current config to connect to another servers is using different port to connect.

e.g

ssh -D 1080 -p 22 username@server1.com

ssh -D 1081 -p 22 username@server2.com

Now what I would like to have to share the same port from the same box.

ssh -D 1080 -p 22 username@server1.com

ssh -D 1080 -p 22 username@server2.com

But when I share it, I will get below error:

bind: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener: cannot listen to port: 1080
Could not request local forwarding.

How could I configure the same port? help. thank you.

I want to share the same port because this is needed when configuring firewall in Citrix Firewall on other machine, not needed to many many ports and keep changing when changing connection.

thank you.

Comment: Why do you need more then one connection?  The -D port number selected should not make an difference to the any computer other then on ssh client, and by default that will listen on the loopback interface which is usually immune from firewall blocking.

Answer (score 1):

You can only do that if you have two different IP addresses on that machine. If it's only for local usage, you can use the 127.0.0.1/8 address space like in:

```
ssh -D 127.0.0.1:1080 -p 22 username@server1.com
ssh -D 127.0.0.2:1080 -p 22 username@server2.com
```

Best of luck,
João Miguel Neves

Comment: Hi Joao,

still i m getting the same error.

is it possible for for you to guide me? thanks

Comment: Any chance that port 1080 will be occupied in the client machine? Please post the output of `netstat -nat | grep 1080` to check.